# How long can it take for an alpha-gal allergy to develop after a tick bite?

Tags: allergy, meat

Can symptoms start months after a tick bite or would the allergy develop within days or weeks?

---

<sub>Edit: I have tried the below sources for information:

▷ Google `alpha gal allergy development time from tick bite`

▷ Google `alpha gal allergy onset time from tick bite`

▷ https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4235259/ (Quote: *the patient reported being bitten by ticks 2 months before the reaction.*)

▷ https://www.cdc.gov/ticks/alpha-gal/index.html

▷ https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/alpha-gal-syndrome/symptoms-causes/syc-20428608

▷ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-gal_allergy

▷ https://www.healthline.com/health/allergies/alpha-gal

▷ https://www.jacionline.org/article/S0091-6749(15)00076-7/fulltext (Quote: *At this time, red meat allergy developed in 3 members of our group, and each one distinctly remembered being bitten by ticks weeks or months before the development of symptoms*)</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment @CareyGregory. I have updated the question with more information